# What is the fastest algorithm for Weighted Planar Max Cut

Tags: time-complexity

In 1990's, the paper [Unifying Maximum Cut and Minimum Cut of a Planar Graph](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.137.5518) described an
$O(n^{3/2}\log n)$-time algorithm for Weighted Planar Max Cut, a landmark in the field.

Recently, this paper appeared:

> Min st-Cut Oracle for Planar Graphs with Near-Linear Preprocessing Time 
>   http://arxiv.org/abs/1003.1320

I was wondering if the time for Weighted Planar Max Cut could be improved from $O(n^{3/2}\log n)$ to $O(n \log^c n)$ for some small constant $c$, using ideas from this paper?

In general, have any improvements in Weighted Planar Max Cut been published?

Answer (score 7):

Shih, Wu, and Kuo's "unifying" paper reduces the planar maximum cut problem to two related problems in planar graphs: (1) maximum-weight bipartite matching and (2) minimum cycle (aka weighed girth).  Both problems are solved in $O(n^{3/2}\log n)$ time using divide-and-conquer algorithms that rely on Lipton and Tarjan's planar separator theorem.

After a long series of improvements, the minimum-weight cycle in a weighted planar graph can now be computed in $O(n \log\log n)$ time using a recent algorithm of [Łącki and Sankowski](http://arxiv.org/abs/1104.4890) (2011).

However, I am unaware of any improvement on the time to find maximum-weight matchings, which means **Shih, Wu, and Kuo's $O(n^{3/2}\log n)$ time algorithm is still the fastest algorithm known** (at least to me) for weighted planar max-cut.

Comment: What's the fastest open source solve in practice for Max Cut?